# Perspective view in Tikz/pgfplots when plotting points from a file

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to apply perspective view when plotting 3d data points from a file? I have seen solutions of perspective transforms applied to drawing of objects (since you can change the placement of points on the object to give it a perspective look) but not sure if it can be applied to existing points when reading them from a file.

My current code is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [axis equal, view={0}{0}]
\addplot3+ [only marks,mark size=0.05, blue] table[x index=1,y index=0, z 
index=2] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I can change the view angle at most but the points do not converge to a vanishing point. I would like a vanishing point.

Edit: I have added a MWE. The data file is [here](https://gofile.io/d/EkkFj3). It represents a cylinder. When proper perspective is applied, the points should converge to a vanishing point

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. It's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: @Andrew done. Both MWE and data file